# How to trim a vector when last values are zeros

Tags: r

I've got a vector that looks like this:

```
x <- c(0, runif(3), 0, 0, runif(5), 0, runif(2), rep(0, 10))
```

I want to remove all the zeros that are at the end of vector, but not those which appear between non-zero values. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: it's not a real duplicate as he only wants to remove them at the end, though the solutions are straightforward to translate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out `x[1 : max(which(x != 0))]`

```
 [1] 0.0000000 0.0297684 0.6745141 0.1008348 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3704074 0.2195432 0.1595944 0.4764559
[11] 0.5712587 0.0000000 0.4233239 0.4611238
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove right side only:

```
x[!!rev(cumsum(rev(x)))]
# or 
x[rev(cumsum(rev(x))) != 0]
x[as.logical(rev(cumsum(rev(x))))]
```

Comment: it removed first 0

Comment: ok now corrected

Comment: Maybe slightly more readable solution with `x[rev(cumsum(rev(x))) != 0]`. +1 for the clever idea of `cumsum` and `rev` anyway.

Comment: could you explain the use of `!!`? I thought double negation leave us with original expression, i.e. `rev(cumsum(rev(x)))`, but the results of `x[!!rev(cumsum(rev(x)))]` and `x[rev(cumsum(rev(x)))]` are different

Comment: yes but ANG has the most readable one :), so I need the most compact one ;)

Comment: double negation leaves you with the original expression if you start with a logical, but here the first `!` also coerces to logical, so `!!x`  is just short for `as.logical` basically (here, not in tidyverse functions where the `!!` operator has a special meaning).